# JAVA JDialog JButton pressed

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jdialog

I found some code, but I don't understand what is really happening.
In this case there is a JFrame that creates a JDialog when a JButton is pressed. When another JButton is pressed in the JDialog, the JFrame must get a signal.

In this case there is a private boolean isOk in the JDialog and a private boolean getIsOk that is returning the isOk. When the button is pressed, the ActionPerformed method implemented from ActionListener is changing the valuea of isOk to true.

In the ActionPerformed method of the JFrame is an if-statment: if(dialog.isOk()). Is JAVA repeating this if statement until the method is returning true? I don't think so, but it is happening on my screen.

Comment: You need to do some research into "modal dialogs", I might start with [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and [How to use modality in dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html), which is a little more advanced but migth help

Comment: Thanks! So after making a modal dialog visible the code stops and go to the JDialog, and when the JDialog is hidden, the code will start to check the if statement?   JDialog jd = new MainDialog(this);   if(jd.isOk()){

Comment: As a summary, yes